# How to preselect items in ExtJS MultiSelector search box

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Is there a way to manipulate the MultiSelector Search component to preselect some items?

Relevant links:

[MultiSelector KitchenSink example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/examples/kitchensink/#multi-selector)
[MultiSelector Docs Sencha page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.view.MultiSelector.html)
[MultiSelectorSearch Docs Sencha page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.view.MultiSelectorSearch.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by selecting records in the MultiSelectorSearch component on afterrender:

```
search: {
    ...
    listeners:
    {
        afterrender: function(cpt)
        {
             // existing items store is sent through the MultiSelector config
             cpt.selectRecords(me.getExistingStore().getData());
         }
    }
}
```